# How to do a login page for third party service without letting them sign on?

Tags: php, security, login

We have a unique situation (at least for me, first time seeing this).

We have a web form where accountants can fill in requests and that part is taken care of.  But after their login we redirect them to a third-party website where we need more information from them. The process is crazy right now since we have to give our account login info to all people filing with us.  So is there a way in PHP or any other solution where we can after that form on our website auto login with our information to that third party website in a way that our credentials are not visible to the users using the service?

Comment: This should be on Stack Overflow, methinks. Could be wrong though.

Comment: Do you mean like an OpenAuth implementation?

Comment: Hmm, I think I'd worry about the structure of the solution (I know that this isn't really an answer) - is there an API you can use to push the data to the 3rd party site instead of getting your client's to log in ??

Answer (score 2):

Your solution will mostly be dependent upon the workings of that third-party web site.

1. If they support some kind of third-party security like OpenAuth you may be able to use that.
2. Perhaps you can wrap their web site in your own code.  Do not redirect your user's browser to their site, but instead proxy the connection through your page.  Then you can intercept the login page and provide credentials without the end-user even knowing that there was a login.
3. Provide individual accounts on that third party site.  Probably not ideal, as now people have to manage their own credentials, but perhaps better than nothing.

Lastly, do be aware about the terms-of-service for the third-party site you are using.  Given you are using it as part of *your* workflow, do they allow for that?  Support it?  Explicitly disallow it such that you could find yourself cut off?

Comment: Thanks for suggesitions! how can i do #2?

Comment: Merely redirect and wrap their pages in your own code.  Have you not seen sites that when you visit a link from them, leave a bar or other navigation tool at the top of the screen? So they ask *you* for a page, you do various http-GET to their web site to get information to build your own page.